# skeletal structure of dimethylamine? HN(CH3)2

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, amines

I don't understand how to draw this skeleton. 
 I know there is a NH2 in an amine structure, but this only has NH? 
and dimethyl means there a 2 identical single side chains right? but where on the skeletal structure are they? 
I'm totally stuck as to how the skeletal structure is supposed to look.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/vcr20cr.png The $\ce{-NH2}$ group is only in a primary amine. This is a secondary amine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at the skeletal structure of different types of amines:

[image]

I hope it's clear now.

Comment: this helps heaps, thanks! I was almost on the right track but I thought the solution was too simple and that I had it wrong